# Java's '==' operator on doubles

Tags: java, floating-point, equals-operator

This method returns 'true'. Why ?

```
public static boolean f() {
   double val = Double.MAX_VALUE/10;
   double save = val;
   for (int i = 1; i < 1000; i++) {
       val -= i;
   }
   return (val == save);
}
```

Comment: because `val` contains the same value than `save`?

Comment: This is simply "How does floating-point arithmetic work?" rephrased once more.

Comment: how come ? val and save had the same value and then the 'for' loop changed val's value while save's value was kept the same.

Comment: That's where you're wrong. `val` doesn't change. Read any book or online article about floating point arithmetic.

Comment: because the numbers subtracted from val are orders of magnitude less than val and won't impact on its value. @us2012 is of course correct.

Comment: It's easy to say "read up on it", but if you don't know what you're looking for (ie, why it's happening) it's hard to find out the properties which are causing the issue.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html a must-read

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You're subtracting quite a small value (less than 1000) from a *huge* value. The small value is so much smaller than the large value that the closest representable value to the theoretical result is still the original value.

Basically it's a result of the way floating point numbers work.

Imagine we had some decimal floating point type (just for simplicity) which only stored 5 significant digits in the mantissa, and an exponent in the range 0 to 1000.

Your example is like writing 10<sup>999</sup> - 1000... think about what the result of that would be, when rounded to 5 significant digits. Yes, the *exact* result is 99999.....9000 (with 999 digits) but if you can only represent values with 5 significant digits, the closest result is 10<sup>999</sup> again.

Answer (score 2):

When you set `val` to Double.MAX_VALUE/10, it is set to a value approximately equal to `1.7976931348623158 * 10^307`. substracting values like 1000 from that would required a precision on the double representation that is not possible, so it basically leaves `val` unchanged.

Depending on your needs, you may use `BigDecimal` instead of `double`.

Answer (score 2):

`Double.MAX_VALUE` is so big that the JVM does not tell the difference between it and `Double.MAX_VALUE-1000`

if you subtract a number fewer than "1.9958403095347198E292" from `Double.MAV_VALUE` the result is still `Double.MAX_VALUE`.

```
System.out.println(  
            new BigDecimal(Double.MAX_VALUE).equals( new BigDecimal(  
                        Double.MAX_VALUE - 2.E291) )  
                ); 

System.out.println(  
           new BigDecimal(Double.MAX_VALUE).equals( new BigDecimal(  
                        Double.MAX_VALUE - 2.E292) )  
                       );
```

Ouptup:

true

false

Answer (score 1):

A double does not have enough precision to perform the calculation you are attempting. So the result is the same as the initial value.

It is nothing to do with the `==` operator.

Answer (score 1):

`val` is a big number and when subtracting `1` (or even `1000`) from it, the result cannot be expressed properly as a `double` value. The representation of this number `x` and `x-1` is the same, because `double` only has a limited number of bits to represent an unlimited number of numbers.

Answer (score 1):

`Double.MAX_VALUE` is a huge number compared to 1 or 1000. `Double.MAX_VALUE-1` is generally equals to `Double.MAX_VALUE`. So your code roughly does nothing when substracting 1 or 1000 to `Double.MAX_VALUE/10`.
Always remember that:

1. `double`s or `float`s are just approximations of real numbers, they are just rationals not equally distributed among the reals
2. you should use very carefully arithmetic operators between `double`s or `float`s which are not close (there is many other rules such like this...)
3. in general, never use `double`s or `float` if you need arbitrary precision

Answer (score 0):

Because `double` is a [floating point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) numeric type, which is a way of *approximating* numeric values.  Floating point representations encode numbers so that we can store numbers much larger or smaller than we normally could.  However, not all numbers can be represented in the given space, so multiple numbers get rounded to the same floating point value.

As a simplified example, we might want to be able to store values ranging from -1000 to 1000 in some small amount of space where we would normally only be able to store -10 to 10.  So we could round all values to the nearest thousand and store them in the small space: -1000 gets encoded as `-10`, -900 gets encoded as `-9`, 1000 gets encoded as `10`.  But what if we want to store -999? The closest value we can encoded is -1000, so we have to encode -999 as the same value as -1000: `-10`.

In reality, floating point schemes are much more complicated than the example above, but the concept is similar.  Floating point representations of numbers can only represent *some* of all the possible numbers, so when we have a number that can't be represented as part of the scheme, we have to round it to the closest representable value.

In your code, all values within 1000 of `Double.MAX_VALUE / 10` automatically get rounded to `Double.MAX_VALUE / 10`, which is why the computer thinks `(Double.MAX_VALUE / 10) - 1000 == Double.MAX_VALUE / 10`.

Answer (score 0):

The result of a floating point calculation is the closest representable value to the exact answer. This program:

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    double val = Double.MAX_VALUE/10;
    System.out.println(val);
    System.out.println(Math.nextAfter(val, 0));
  }
}
```

prints:

```
1.7976931348623158E307
1.7976931348623155E307
```

The first of these numbers is your original val. The second is the largest double that is less than it.

When you subtract 1000 from 1.7976931348623158E307, the exact answer is between those two numbers, but very, very much closer to 1.7976931348623158E307 than to 1.7976931348623155E307, so the result will be rounded to 1.7976931348623155E307, leaving val unchanged.